# How can we detect hotkeys registered by other apps?

Tags: winapi, keyboard, hook, hotkeys

Is it possible to detect all the hotkeys registered by the OS as well as software applications currently running? Any native or managed approach on the Windows platform? I know that the RegisterHotKey function returns false if the hotkey is already registered, but what I am looking for is an approach, method, etc. that will give me a list of registered hotkeys. Looping all possible combinations with RegisterHotKey does not sound like a good idea. Anything more efficient?

Comment: Sorry, I just accepted the answers.

Comment: Don't just accept an answer just because someone told you to accept an answer. The answer is very poor and misleading.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This program manages to do that but dont know how,
http://diamondcs.com.au/dse/detection/hotkeys.php

The programs like these, scan the handles of all the processes,thereby revealing hot keys of all applications
This could be a time consuming process

THis is an open source application that deals with the Nitty Gritty Details of all processes

http://sourceforge.net/projects/processhacker/

Comment: this is not an answer, is it?

Comment: take that @phunehehe,

kidding :).